# ¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término array?

Tags: c++, c, programación-bajo-nivel

Conocí el término al estar aprendiendo C en el libro de Deitel y Deitel en el cuál se mencionaba ***arreglo*** para referirse al término que en inglés se conoce como ***array***, sin embargo al estar dentro de la jerga de programación en español nunca veo que se utilize el término ***arreglo*** para referirse a ***array***, sino ***vector*** o ***matriz*** de datos, así que al no ver el término utilizándose mas que en el libro quisiera saber cuál es la traducción correcta de ***array*** refiriéndose a datos subsecuentes en memoria a los cuales se puede acceder mediante un puntero que apunte al primer elemento y aritméticamente pueda acceder de uno en uno hasta el último elemento, esto lo menciono para no confundir por ejemplo con la clase de C++ ***std::vector*** que es una abstracción más compleja.

Comment: ¿ Donde está es @PaperBirdMaster cuando se le necesita ? No estoy seguro de si está pregunta es correcta en este sitio, o debería publicarse en [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Igual de que tampoco estoy seguro de que exista una respuesta *universal*: Hay quién utiliza *array*, otros *arreglo*, los menos *vector* y aun menos los que usan *formación*. Y algunos usamos `std::vector` (con el *namespace* completo, y formato de código) para distinguir las clases (y tipos en general). Lo dicho, no estoy seguro de que exista una traducción *correcta*.

Comment: Y si tiene varias dimensiones no es raro llamarlo matriz. En el Diccionario de la Real Academia (por recurrir a alguna autoridad en la materia) no dice nada... Otra autoridad es el pionero que elaboró el primer diccionario inglés-español para informática, allá por el 85. En [esta entrevista](https://www.eldiario.es/hojaderouter/informatica-Espana-origenes-historia-traduccion-Antonio_Vaquero_0_453205398.html) defiende que array se debe traducir por _formación_. Lo cierto es que como dice @Trauma eso se ve poco. Personalmente yo lo dejo como _array_.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta iría mejor en [Spanish Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com) recuerda leer su recorrido y ver que preguntas entran en de la temática del sitio

Comment: Pregunta formulada en [spanish.se] --> [¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término “array”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29066/1674) pues ya no podía migrarse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En 2013 pregunté a la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) sobre la terminología que desde dicha institución consideraban adecuada para el lenguaje técnico en Español. Mi pregunta no iba sobre el término *array* si no sobre la "*Españolización*" de los términos *Get*, *Set* y *Reset* como "*Getear*", "*Setear*" y "*Resetear*", pero aunque su respuesta es en relación a esos términos, puede ser usada en tu duda:

> En relación con su consulta, le remitimos la siguiente información:
>
> La cuestión es que si en español existen términos como *establecer*, *restablecer* y *obtener*, que son transparentes para quienes los emplean y no dejan lugar a dudas sobre su uso, no hay motivo para crear otros nuevos, como no lo hay para utilizar calcos del inglés, solo porque el  resultado de estos tenga alguna sílaba menos. Ahora bien, es cierto que el idioma pertenece a los hablantes, que son los responsables de su evolución histórica, pues lo van construyendo con su uso diario. De modo que son los especialistas de cada materia quienes tienen la oportunidad de asumir y difundir el empleo de determinadas voces y dejar al margen otras en las publicaciones de su especialidad.
>
> Reciba un cordial saludo
>
> ---
>
> Departamento de «Español al día» Real Academia Española

No creo que hayan cambiado de criterio en seis años, por lo que creo que la respuesta sigue siendo válida y aplicable en el contexto de tu duda:

**¿Cuál es la traducción al español correcta del término array?** la que nosotros como programadores popularicemos. Es muy frustrante buscar información sobre programación en el [segundo idioma más hablado del planeta (Enero 2019)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Lenguas_por_n%C3%BAmero_de_hablantes_nativos) (por delante del Inglés) y encontrar apenas nada. Los principales culpables de esto somos los programadores hispanohablantes, que no creamos contenido en nuestro idioma; para acabar con este problema debemos crear todo el contenido que podamos en nuestro idioma y hacer lo posible por popularizarlo, voy a listar (en orden alfabético) las palabras candidatas y mi opinión sobre las mismas... a partir de ahí, que gane la mejor:

- **Arreglo**: La más extendida hasta la fecha, personalmente no me gusta porque creo que en Español (España) no transmite la idea de un conjunto de datos del mismo tipo con tamaño predefinido; parece más una traducción casi literal del término arr(ay|eglo).
- **Colección**: Un término que transmite muy bien la idea de conjunto de datos, pero no necesariamente transmite la idea de homogeneidad, personalmente me gusta bastante pero más para contenedores en general que para un tipo particular.
- **Formación**: En mi opinión, es la palabra que mejor transmite la idea de una colección de datos del mismo tipo con tamaño determinado de antemano ya que es muy fácil hacer la analogía con las formaciones *del mundo real* tanto de [una dimensión](http://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/34963/Optimized-DSC00415.JPG) como de [dos dimensiones](https://est.zetaestaticos.com/extremadura/img/noticias/1/118/1118831_1.jpg).
- **Matriz**: Una palabra adecuada para transmitir el concepto pero, que se puede confundir con el homónimo [matemático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1ticas)) haciéndola inadecuada.
- **Vector**: Inadecuado porque se puede confundir con el homónimo [matemático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_vectorial).

Por desgracia, casi todo mi texto es basado en opiniones, así que votaré en consecuencia.

Comment: Aunque esté basado en opiniones, creo que siempre hay matices y que esta pregunta sí debería mantenerse abierta

Comment: @eferion Es cierto, creo que no hay una respuesta concreta para mi pregunta, sin embargo me pareció la explicación más acertada.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, creo que me quedo con **formación** como bien tú lo mencionas una colección de datos con un mismo tamaño o tipo, subsecuentemente formada y que puede tener una, dos o varias dimensiones.

Comment: Pues creo que te falta una: tabla. A mi, particularmente, no me gusta ni arreglo (no existe esa palabra en español con ese significado), ni colección, ni mucho menos formación. Y vector y matriz tienen el problema de la confusión.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix "*Tabla*" transmite (al menos a mi) una idea de bidimensionalidad (filas y columnas) por lo que no sería adecuada para transmitir la idea de un conjunto de datos homogéneos de una sola dimensión.

Answer (score 4):

La traducción literal más aproximada sería, en este caso, *colección*. Un *array* no es sino una colección de elementos. Ahora bien, dentro del mundo de la programación hay muchos términos... generalmente todos ellos importados del inglés. Cada término tiene ciertos matices:

- *vector*: Se entiende por vector a aquella colección de elementos que comparten posiciones contiguas de memoria.
- *arreglo*: Colección, generalmente ordenada, de elementos.
- *matriz*: Una matriz es una agrupación de colecciones. Una matriz no es más que una generalización de un *vector* para *n* dimensiones.

Desde mi experiencia, la traducción más habitual de *array* es *vector*, aunque dado que no es algo que esté estandarizado no creo que se deba generalizar. Es bastante probable que estos términos estén sujetos a los localismos y la cultura propia de cada región o país.